# How to replace round bracket tag in javascript string

Tags: javascript, string

I have trouble with changing round bracket tag in Javascript. I try to do this:

```
var K = 1;
var Text = "This a value for letter K: {ValueOfLetterK}";
Text = Text.replace("{ValueOfLetterK}", K);
```

and after that I get:

```
Text = "This a value for letter K: {ValueOfLetterK}"
```

What can be done to make this work? When I remove round brackets it works fine.

Comment: It works for me in IE and Firefox - which browser have you tested this in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace more than one occurrence, you need a regular expression with 'g' (=global) switch

```
 Text = Text.replace(/{ValueOfLetterK}/g, K);
```

If you're looking for a more generic way to replace placeholders in the string, this is how it could be done:

```
var myVars = { A: 1, B: 2 };
var Text = "This a value for a {valueOfA} and b {valueOfB} and a again {valueOfA}";
Text = Text.replace(/{valueOf(\w+)}/g, function() {
   var varName = arguments[1];
   return myVars[varName];
});

alert(Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in Chrome and Firefox... Try to escape curly braces and see what happens:

```
Text = Text.replace("\{ValueOfLetterK\}", K);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with your code. I tried it in Firefox and IE, and it worked for me. Let me know witch browser yor are using.

```
<html>
<head> 
<script>
var K = 1; 
var Text = "This a value for letter K: {ValueOfLetterK}"; 
Text = Text.replace("{ValueOfLetterK}", K); 
alert(Text)
</script> 

</head><body>
    </body> 

    </html>
```